# Restore spied/stubbed function with Sinon sandbox

Tags: javascript, sinon, stub, monkeypatching, spy

A Sinon sandbox (or `sinon` instance) is passed from outside to script scope. Internal function (not a method) can be optionally spied/stubbed with Sinon sandbox.

Sinon is involved in some kind of monkey-patching here (not unit-testing) .Sinon sandbox concept fitted the use case really well - until this moment.

I proceed from the fact that function spy cannot be replaced with method spy. It is not a perfect scenario but the design cannot be changed.

```
const originalCallback = callback;

callback = sinonSandbox.spy(callback);
thirdPartyFn(callback);

// how can this be achieved?
// sinonSandbox.onRestore(() => thirdPartyFn(originalCallback));
```

How can the app be notified when sandbox is restored to restore spied function? Is there a hook to be launched on 'restore' event? Are there third-party Sinon extensions that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, Sinon doesn't have a mechanism for notification on sandbox restore. Since the job of `sandbox.restore()` is [to call `restore` method](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/v1.17.4/lib/sinon/sandbox.js#L96) on [each faked function](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/v1.17.4/lib/sinon/collection.js#L54), I've ended with patching fake's own `restore` as the most suitable solution:

```
const originalCallback = callback;
callback = sinonSandbox.spy(callback);

const originalRestore = callback.restore;
callback.restore = function (...args) {
  originalRestore.apply(this, args);
  thirdPartyFn(originalCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd mock/stub the restore function :

```
var originalRestore = sinonSandbox.restore;

sinonSandBox.restore = () => {
  originalRestore();
  // insert code here
};
```

Comment: I hoped to avoid this, but yes, it looks like it's all about monkey-patching. Btw, I believe it should be `originalRestore.call(sinonSandbox)` (not sure about arguments, but it looks like `restore` doesn't have some).

Answer (score 1):

Originally, sinon doesn't publish any events or offer any hooks, but you can create one:

```
var spyInstance = sinonSandbox.spy(callback);

(function (original) {

    spyInstance.restore = function() {
        original.apply(this, arguments); // call the original restore function
        events.publish("sinon", "restore-end"); // publish the event to decouple this module from receiving module
    }

})(spyInstance.restore);
```

then, somewhere down the line in another module:

```
events.subscribe("sinon", "restore-end", function() {
    // call some code to execute when the sinon spy is restored
});
```

events object is just your global pub/sub module or something like that.